Getting only status string in HealthCheckResult from ASP.NET Core health check endpoint
In my ASP.NET Core app, I implemented IHealthCheck to return status 503 until warmup of the app is done. But when I call this endpoint from Postman, I see only status string in the output, and not the actual JSON for:
Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckResult

Why am I not getting the full JSON response? I expected a JSON similar to this:
{
   "Status": "Healthy",
   "Description": "The Initialization task has completed."
}

Instead I see:
Healthy
Attaching image below from postman:

The IHealthCheck depends on another object to get the state of application warm up. Based on that it returns Healthy or Unhealthy.
   public class StartupHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
  {
      private volatile bool _isReady;
      private readonly IGlobalState _globalState;
      public StartupHealthCheck(IGlobalState globalState)
          => _globalState = globalState;

  

        public bool StartupCompleted
          {
              get => _isReady;
              set => _isReady = value;
          }
    
          public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
              HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
          {
              if (StartupCompleted && _globalState.PercentageInitialized == 100)
              {
                  return HealthCheckResult.Healthy("The Initialization task has completed.");
              }
    
              return new HealthCheckResult(HealthStatus.Unhealthy, $"The Initialization task is still running at - {_globalState.PercentageInitialized}%.");
          }
      }


Hello @qwerty123, the link you provided points to Stackoverflow's home page. I think it would be a good idea to post an actual screenshot of what you're getting, or even the actual text. This would further improve your question.

I edited just now

Hi @qwerty123, how do you implement the IHealthCheck? How is the endponit code like?

@Rena - added the IHealthCheck implementation in the description

Hi @qwerty123, i have shared the answer. Pls check.

You need custom the output response in Program.cs for example:
static Task WriteResponse(HttpContext context, HealthReport result)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var options = new JsonWriterOptions
    {
        Indented = true
    };
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, options))
        {
            var healthCheck = result.Entries.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteString("Status", healthCheck.Status.ToString());
            writer.WriteString("Description", healthCheck.Description);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
    }
}

In .NET 6 or later, register the services in the Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGlobalState, GlobalState>(); // Assuming IGlobalState is registered

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<StartupHealthCheck>("startup_health_check");


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        ResponseWriter = WriteResponse
    });
});
app.UseAuthorization();    
app.MapControllers();
  
app.Run();

Reference: Customize output
